# SMS from client to server With Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio

This is my server side code for twilio SMS system. And i wanna send messages to different number. how can i send that dynamic number in that 'to' ?

```
client.messages
    .create({
       body: 'Kodun: '+req.body.otpCode,
       from: '+17274319566', // Thats My twilio number
       to: numberr // This Side take a number from front side input
     })
    .then(message => res.json(message))
    .catch(message => res.json(message))
    .done();
});
```

All server side code in here :

```
const http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var router = express.Router();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});   
router.get('/2', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: '2' });
}); 
router.post('/sendsms', function(req, res) {
  const accountSid = 'twilio_account_sid';
  const authToken = 'twilio_auth_token';
  const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
  const numberr = req.body.number;
  client.messages
    .create({
       body: 'Kodun: '+req.body.otpCode,
       from: '+17274319566',
       to: numberr
     })
    .then(message => res.json(message))
    .catch(message => res.json(message))
    .done();
}); 
app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: First point, please don't put your account credentials in questions like this. I've edited it, but you should go generate a new auth token in your Twilio console and cancel your existing one.

Comment: Other than that, your code looks fine, what is going wrong? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to send a list of numbers through the app? I just built an app recently to mass send SMS and I sent an array of phone numbers through a POST request to implement that MessageResource method.

If sending multiple numbers though, I would recommend using a Messaging Service from Twilio so that Twilio can load balance your From numbers.

Edit: What does your client side code look like? Or if you are using Postman, what does your Request Body look like?